# alwaysRun parameter in TestNG

Tags: java, testing, annotations, testng

Can someone please explain me when `@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)` should execute. Will it execute when `@test` method is skipped. In documentation is written so, but I have observed different behavior.

Example:
Code:

```
public class testing{

    @Test
    public void testCase2(){
        System.out.println("in test case 2");
        Assert.assertEquals(1,2);
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "testCase2" })
    public void testcase3(){
        System.out.println("OK");
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void afterMethod2() {
        System.out.println("in afterMethod");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
in test case 2
in afterMethod
FAILED: testCase2
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [2] but found [1]
   at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
   at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:494)
   at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:123)
   at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:370)
   at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:380)
   at app.testing.testCase2(testing.java:22)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
   at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
   at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
   at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

SKIPPED: testcase3

===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

Shouldn't `@After` method be executed twice, also after skipped `@Test`?
Thanks for answer in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) says

> For after methods (afterSuite, afterClass, ...): If set to true, this
>   configuration method will be run even if one or more methods invoked
>   previously failed or was skipped.

So I think it should execute after skipped test method.

Comment: Also it will make the method run even if it doesn't belong to the current group being executed

Answer (score 2):

Even though the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) has stated that

> For after methods (afterSuite, afterClass, ...): If set to true, this
> configuration method will be run even if one or more methods invoked
> previously failed or was skipped.

However, in configfailurepolicy annotations, the following is stated when there's any test failures

> configfailurepolicy: Whether TestNG should continue to execute the
> remaining tests in the suite or skip them if an @before* method fails.
> Default behavior is skip.

BTW, @AfterMethod is not a test method but a configuration one.

Answer (score 0):

alwaysRun on @Test: A method (say method2) having this testng attribute willalways run even if the method on which it depends (dependsOnMethods="Method1") failed and it is referred as soft dependency in testNG terminology.

alwaysRun on @Before or @After annotated methods: if @BeforeSuite fails and @BeforeClass has alwaysRun = true then it won't be skipped. (although test case may get skipped)

```
public class TestAlwaysRun{

    @BeforeSuite
    public void toFailBeforeSuite() {
        System.out.println("I'm beforeSuite, I will fail");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void toFailBeforeTest() {
        System.out.println("BUG: I'm beforeTest, I will fail");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void toFailBeforeClass() {
        System.out.println("BUG: I'm beforeClass, I will fail");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void toFailBeforeMethod() {
        System.out.println("BUG: I'm beforeMethod, I will fail");
        //throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Test
    public void tetsCase() {
        System.out.println("I'm a Test Case");
    }
}

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
I'm beforeSuite, I will fail
BUG: I'm beforeTest, I will fail
BUG: I'm beforeMethod, I will fail
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest toFailBeforeTest
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at testngTutorial.ABC.toFailBeforeTest(ABC.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:637)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:627)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:589)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite toFailBeforeSuite
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at testngTutorial.ABC.toFailBeforeSuite(ABC.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:317)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED: tetsCase
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at testngTutorial.ABC.toFailBeforeTest(ABC.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:637)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:627)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:589)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score -3):

I think here you have given `dependsOnMethods = { "testCase2" }`
That is why your second test itself isn't triggered and so aftermethod doesn't execute.
Please remove that depends and check ..it will execute aftermethod twice.